# Insertig datas, if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL code, how should I change it to insert datas only if they aren't exist in my table. thanks for your answers:)

```
INSERT INTO stages_done(id_booked_proj, id_stage) 
SELECT booked_proj.id, stages.id_st
FROM booked_proj, stages 
WHERE booked_proj.name='home' AND stages.name_st= 'sm'"
```

Comment: What's the PK in `stages_done` table?

Comment: @Gerry I have PK as autoincrement and I should insert only these columns.. but they should not be repeated in connection "id_booked_proj-id_stage" However id_booked_proj and id_stage could be repeted

Comment: Check the updated answer, you can accomplish that by adding an index based on those two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSERT IGNORE`, this way the row won't be inserted if it results in a duplicate key:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO stages_done(id_booked_proj, id_stage) 
SELECT booked_proj.id, stages.id_st
FROM booked_proj, stages 
WHERE booked_proj.name='home' AND stages.name_st= 'sm'"
```

Any duplicate key in columns either with PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints will be ignored.

---

If you have writing access, you can add a constraint to your table, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `stages_done` ADD UNIQUE `id_booked_proj_id_stage_index` (`id_booked_proj`, `id_stage`);
```

Where `id_booked_proj_id_stage_index` can be any name you pick as long as it is unique.

Comment: I want, that columns aren't repeated in such connection: "id_booked_proj- id_stage" is it possible?

Comment: @Roshki Yes, just add a constraint to your table with id_booked_proj and id_stage. Check updated answer.